# Accesing data through a javascript object and printing it on html page

Tags: javascript

I have a object in which each key has a string corresponds to it for ex `{ 0 :'hello\nworld', 1:'\njavascript\nis\nawesome' }` now I want to print this in html page and for each `\n` there should be a break line for example -

```
hello(new line)
world(new line)
javascript(new line)
is(new line)
awesome(new line)
```

as a new programmer I don't know hoe to do it any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). and regular expression.By using `g` flag in regex you can replace all the `\n` with `<br>`.

```js
let obj = { 0 :'hello\nworld', 1:'\njavascript\nis\nawesome' }
for(let key in obj){
  let reg = new RegExp('\n',"g");
  document.body.innerHTML += obj[key].replace(/\n/g,'<br>'); 
}
```

Comment: @PM 77-1 ok now i have edited I forgot that i need to use regex and `g` flag

Comment: Good.  For others please notice "*If pattern is a **string**, only the **first occurrence** will be replaced*" in the docs.

Comment: it works fine but if i want to add words after each string for example after hello i want to display vijay then a blank line then world then some word and then blank line

Answer (score 0):

replace `\n` by `<br/>` and put it all in any visible html tag, it should show your text and go back to line whenever a `<br/>` is met.